# How to prevent a GridView to resize (ASP)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP:Gridview whose Columns might change visibility depending of users clicks.
I would like the layout not to resize when controls visibility changes.

Here is the Gridview code:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" Font-Size="Small" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="text-align:right" Font-Size="XX-Small" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Width="150" Height="10" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="doc ">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" Font-Size="Small" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_Doc" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("MyProp") %>' Width="50px" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CB_CheckedChanged" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Book">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" Font-Size="XX-Small" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HF_Id" Value='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 50px;">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB_Book" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("MyProp2") %>' Width="30" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CB_CheckedChanged" />
                                    </td>

                                 <!-- A few more controls that might be visible or not depending if user clicks previous CheckBox -->

                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Default it displays this way:
[image]

When I click on the right Checkbox, the GridView has the bad idea to resize this way:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this resizing?
As far as I can see, there would definitely be enough space to display all of the controls whose visibility changes, without resizing.

Thx in advance.

EDIT: the 2 updaded images from the post appear so compressed that we cannot see the problem. :(
 But the first column width is decreased of -30% causing the whole page layout to be broken.

Comment: What are the differences between the above two images ?!

Answer (score 0):

Put your gridView inside a div tag and set its attributes i.e.

```
<div id="ScrollList" style="height: 500px; overflow: auto">
<!-- your gridview -->
</div>
```

And also set the width of your boundfields i.e.

```
ItemStyle-Width="100%" ControlStyle-Width="100%"
```

Hope it helps.